# Switching circuit

Tags: switches

I am making a switching circuit with two input sources A and B of 5 volts each and one or more outputs C1, C2, C3 etc.
Source A is constant and source B is variable, has two states on and of.
Source B must change the state of output C1, if source B is on output C1 is off, if source B in off, output C1 is on.
Outputs C2, C3 etc. are used as grounding if necessary.
The circuit must not contain transistors, diodes, relays or vacuum tubes.

Edit:

I used this circuit simulator ( https://www.falstad.com/circuit/  ) to simulate my circuit:

```
$ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 50 5 50
r 192 192 288 192 0 50
w 288 192 288 272 0
s 288 272 288 352 0 1 false
R 288 352 288 416 0 0 40 6 0 0 0.5
w 192 192 192 256 0
g 96 256 32 256 0
R 64 192 -16 192 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
w 192 192 192 96 0
r 192 96 192 32 0 200
r 96 256 192 256 0 200
g 192 32 192 -16 0
w 64 192 192 192 0
o 11 64 0 4099 5 0.1 0 2 11 3
```

( Import the code above to see the circuit )

[image]

What I did so far, the top grounding is output C1, the left input source is A, the bottom input is B, and the second grounding is C2.

If you look at the scope linked to the wire next to source A, the effect is achieved but I need that to work in output C1 ( top grounding )

Comment: Welcome to EE SE! Is this a homework?

Comment: No, it's something I want to make in my spare time

Comment: Okay. What is your background in EE? What kind of attempt have you done to achieve your goals? Is there any problem in achieving it? What are things that you're not understand? We're not going to design your circuit from scratch, we're going to help to direct you. Please take your time slowly by edit your question to put more details, see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a better question.

Comment: So, what is your question and, can you please justify the rigid (homework like) constraints in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use Falstad.  Could you post a picture of your schematic?

Comment: @Oliver are any active devices such as logic gate ICs not allowed?

Comment: I am trying to make this only from resistors

Comment: Your earth symbols should point to, um, Earth.

Comment: @Oliver Is Morten answer wasn't enough? Is there anything missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your constraints are

> The circuit must not contain transistors, diodes, relays or vacuum tubes.

And that the voltage levels for "off" and "on" are equal for the two outputs C1  Then what you try to achieve is not possible.

I have assumed that no transistors are allowed even in other configurations such as flip-flops, logic gates, opAmps. And that the switch is a signal not originating from a physical switch(in that case get a DPDT switch and you should be good).

If logic gates are allowed, try playing around with them and I think you will figure it out quite quickly ;)

PS the only thing you need as an input is input B since the input of A is constant.